# Installed Ubuntu and now eclipse wont work

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I have just install ubuntu on my laptop as a dual boot. I also install Eclipse but can't get any of my java programs to work. The error message is below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: SquareRootTest : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: SquareRootTest. Program will exit.
```

Comment: You appear to have a different version of Java installed. Did you rebuild your projects with the compiler you have installed in Ubuntu?

Comment: Version 51.0 is Java 7 i guess. Can anyone confirm.

Comment: I have built them again using eclipse but still same issue. Not sure if I am doing it propery

Comment: There's absolutely no evidence, that installing ubuntu in a dual-boot setup is the cause of this. In fact it's a java version issue. Please consider removing the `ubuntu` tag, as it is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that SquareRootTest class was compiled with Java 7 (class Version 51.0) and you are trying to run it with a JVM from an older generation. Try to run java -version to see what JVM you use, also look in the eclipse preferences. You should also clean you project to be sure it is recompiled...

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've copied your project folder from previous OS workspace that contains
compiled `.class` files which i think is the problem in your case.

Anyway, what you can try here is - just delete all your project related `.class` files from workspace and eclipse will automatically recompile all your `.java` files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install java 7 on your ubuntu. Also ensure you make java 7 as the default on your ubuntu desktop. Follow this link in order to do that:

http://www.devsniper.com/ubuntu-12-04-install-sun-jdk-6-7/